# Hyperledger Fabric: Calling Python script from chain code written using Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm developing an application using Hyperledger Fabric wherein an application written in nodeJS calls a chaincode function also written in nodeJS. This chain code function should call a Python script, do something and written the results to the chaincode function. This chaincode function should store the results returned by the Python script on the ledger and return the successful storage status back to the calling application. 
I tried to do this using child process module given by nodeJS in the following way-

```
async mergeModel(ctx, modelNumber1, modelNumber2) {
    console.info('============= START : Merge Model ===========');
    const modelAsBytes1 = await ctx.stub.getState(modelNumber1); // get the model from chaincode state
    const modelAsBytes2 = await ctx.stub.getState(modelNumber2); // get the model from chaincode state

    if (!modelAsBytes1 || modelAsBytes1.length === 0) {
        throw new Error(`${modelNumber1} does not exist`);
    }
    if (!modelAsBytes2 || modelAsBytes2.length === 0) {
        throw new Error(`${modelNumber2} does not exist`);
    }
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',['mergeModel.py', modelAsBytes1, modelAsBytes2]);
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The python script mergeModel.py is stored in the same directory as the chaincode. 
But, this is not calling the python script as expected. 
Is there something I'm missing. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell package is more efficient that nodejs

Comment: Just to clarify, you are calling the script from the chaincode?

Comment: This is very bad practice todo so

Answer (score 1):

```
> This chain code function should call a Python script, do something and
  written the results to the chaincode function.
```

> This is very bad practice, please never do such a thing as it may
>   affect transaction execution. Try to execute your python script in the
>   Nodejs AppServer and once you get the result then invoke the chaincode